# Sphinx seems to force a Order on ID?

Tags: sphinx, ord

I added a new field to my index (`weight`) which is an integer based value I want to sort on.

I added it to the select and invoked it as `sql_attr_uint`

When I call it in my query it shows up. However when I try to sort on it i get strange behavior. It always sorts on the record ID instead. So `Order on ID` is identical to `Order on Weight`.

I've checked the Index pretty thoroughly and can't find a reason why, does sphinx auto-sort on record ID somehow?

I know the details are fairly sparse yet I'm hoping there is some basic explanation I'm missing before asking anyone to delve in further.

As an update: I don't believe the ID field sort has been "imposed" on the index in anyway inadvertently since I can Order by a # of other fields, both integer and text and the results are returned independent of the ID values (e.g sort on last name Record #100 `Adams` will come before Record #1 `Wyatt`)

Yet ordering on `Weight` always returns the same order as ordering by `ID` whether it is asc or desc. No error about the field or index not existing or being sortable, no ignoring the order request (`desc` and `asc` work) it just ignores that particular field value and uses the ID instead.

Further Update:  The Weight value is indexed via a join to the main table indexed by sphinx in the following manner:

```
sql_attr_multi = uint value_Weight from ranged-query; \
SELECT j.id AS ID, IF(s.Weight > 0, 1, 0) AS Weight \
FROM Customers j \
INNER JOIN CustomerSources s ON j.customer_id = s.customer_id \
AND j.id BETWEEN $start AND $end \
ORDER BY s.id; \
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM Customers
```

Once indexed sorting on both `id` and `value_Weight` return the same sort whereas Weight and ID are unrelated.

Comment: I wonder if its simply a problem with the name `weight`. That is what Sphinx uses for the dynamically computed weight when full-text matching.

Comment: Oh, just seen second edit. So your 'weight' attribute, is actully a MVA (multi-value attribute) - even if you only put one value. Not sure you can directly sort by a MVA, because normally it would be a list, so sorting by a list is kinda tricky. You will have to mve the 'JOIN' into the main `sql_query` to make it a normal single attribute

Comment: @barryhunter I get the same issue even if I use totally different names from Weight

Comment: @barryhunter The `Weight` value is actually a flag 0 (No) 1 (Yes). We tried different values because coder read Sphinx can have trouble with 0/1 but no luck. Wondering if simple text Y/N would change anything or is that still an 'MVA'?

Comment: @barryhunter As a somewhat newbie to Sphinx, the germane facts seem to be that a) Sphinx doesn't throw an error on the order when that field is used to order b) the desc and asc are obeyed c) the asc and desc are always on the ID though. To my thinking somehow the join has imposed a sort order on the ID first for that join. I found a similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518313/sphinx-ignores-ranking-always-sorts-in-the-same-order?rq=1 that you answered and wonder if this could be somehow happening during the join?

Comment: @barryhunter What if I changed from `sql_attr_multi` since we are basically pulling in a field from a joined table and if it has a value of 0 setting to 0 and a value > 0 setting to 1. So the 'Weight' is EITHER 1 or 0 there are never multiple values. Really just looking for a field/flag that is `Yes` or `No`

Comment: Well sticking with plain 0/1 is fine, as that can easily be sorted by. I still think the problem is the use of a MVA. Ordering by a MVA silently (probably) fails. Use a standard attribute instead. using sql_attr_unit can even choose a bit width, so can turn it into a 0/1 boolean.

Comment: @barryhunter We decided to move it out of the secondary join and put it in the main index as a join since it is a one-to-one will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes, from 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/mva.html

> Filtering and group-by **(but not sorting)** on MVA attributes is supported.

Can't sort by a MVA attribute (which as noted in comments makes sense, as MVAs usually contain many values, sorting by many values is rather 'tricky'.

When you try, it simply fails. So sorting is falling back on the 'natural' order of the index, which is usually by ID.

Use `sql_attr_unit` instead
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-sql-attr-uint.html
(but will proabbly mean rewriting the `sql_query` to perform the JOIN on `CustomerSources` )

Comment: We removed the join I referred to in the post and just did a join in the initial sql_query and it works fine. Thank you!